# Unityの時間ゲーム

Tags: unity3d

Unityでゲームを作りたいと思っています。
そこで質問ですが
例えばキャラクターが1秒から10秒間画面上に居て
5秒目から7秒目までの間にクリックしたら成功
5秒以前なら失敗
7秒以降でも失敗と言うプログラミングを
作りた
いです。

何からすればいいかわかりません。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 目標があるのは良いことですが、質問の内容が広すぎるように感じます。「プログラミングの経験はあるのか」「Unity自体を使用したことは？」辺りの理解度が第三者からは分からないため、もう少し具体的な内容に絞り込んでもらわないとアドバイスは難しいと思います。 - 参考: [どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 4):

Unity（に限らず広く使われている言語やフレームワーク）には、**チュートリアル**という初心者が使い方を学ぶための教材が公開されています。

以下は全て日本語の資料ですので、これらを利用してUnityの使い方を学んでから、詰まった部分があったらこちらで具体的な質問をするというのをおすすめします。

- [Unity Learn Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/jp/learn/tutorials)
- [はじめてのUnity](http://tutorial.unity3d.jp/)

Answer (score 0):

```
float count; //　時間を管理する小数値
bool gameActive = false; //trueだったらゲーム中
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) //スペースキーを押してゲームスタート
    {
        gameActive = true;  // gameactiveをtrueにしてゲームをスタートさせる
    }

    if(gameActive == true)  //gameactiveがtrueの間はゲームを実行する
    {
        count += Time.deltaTime; //一秒に１増やす
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Enter)) //Enterを押すと実行
        {
            if(count >= 5 && count =< 7) //countが5~7の間の場合
            {
                Debug.Log("成功");
            }
            else //countが5~7以外の場合
            {
                Debug.Log("失敗");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

もしこれでおかしかったら言ってください。
何せこちらもはじめたばっかりなので...